# Gnome on-screen keyboard not working with GTK app [20.04]

Tags: 20.04, gtk, onscreen-keyboard

After upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 the OSK stopped displaying for focused entries in my GTK Desktop app. It still works fine for other GTK apps like firefox, but I'm not sure where to look for a solution. I've seen posts for login screen issues, but haven't found anything on this.

I'm on a standard desktop environment. I updated all dependencies for 20.04. I'd prefer to inherit the Gnome default OSK instead of using onboard, but any tips are greatly appreciated.